# excel find range of a cell in C#

Tags: excel, range, cell

How can the range of a cell in excel be found through C# code?

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[row + 1, col + 1]
```

I want to find out this cell's range.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Excel exposes an object [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx#excelobj_link19). You can access cells, for instance

```
rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[row + 1, col + 1];
```

This statement should select a single cell.
To get all the cells of the row 1 (always as Range):

```
rng = (Excel.Range)ws.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
```

Comment: Thanks but typing rng.Style.Font.Color = Color.Red; worked for whole row(all the cells in the row changed) But I want a single cell to change. Could you provide a better solution?